# Test the return value from a .then or .catch with Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

We're trying to test a function which calls a asynchronous function. The problem is that this fonction return a promise and if we test a value which must be changed in a .then() or a .catch() then the value isn't updated since the part of the code which change this hasn't happened yet.

I'd like my tests to wait for the then or catch.

```
exampleFunction() {
    if (this.path !== this.openFolder) {
        this.myService.asyncFunction(this.openFolder)
          .then((data) => {
          // I do some stuff
           return true;
          })
          .catch((data) => {
            // I do some stuff
            return true;
          });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
}
```

```
it('should return true', () => {
    const aPath = 'SOMETHING';
    component.path = aPath;
    component.openFolder = aPath;
    component.openBrowse();
    expect(component.path).toBe(Path);
  });
```

(Of course, i mocked my service and my function look like this)

```
async asyncFunction(newPath) {
    new Promise<ServiceResult>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (newPath == 'SOMETHING') {
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            reject(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Any helps would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution i did this :

```
it('should return true', (**done**) => {
    const aPath = 'SOMETHING';
    component.path = aPath;
    component.openFolder = aPath;
    component.openBrowse().then((result) => {
        expect(component.path).toBe(Path);
        done();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fakeAsync` and `tick` (both from `@angular/core/testing`).

```
it('should return true', fakeAsync(() => {
    const aPath = 'SOMETHING';
    component.path = aPath;
    component.openFolder = aPath;
    component.openBrowse();
    tick();
    expect(component.path).toBe(Path);
}));
```

`fakeAsync` makes the test body run in a "special fakeAsync test zone".

`tick` "simulates the passage of time until all pending asynchronous activities finish"

So if you use a combination of these, you can have your asynchronous test looking more like a synchronous one.

Source [Angular - Testing Asynchronous](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync)

Comment: Adding fakeAsync and a tick return a 1 timer still in the queue. Do you know why ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "return a 1 timer still in the queue". Could you elaborate?